# how can I edit a cell in a tableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented a `viewController` that contains a `tableView` which display user's data(firstName , lastName , birthday..) fetched from login Facebook or twitter or google Plus .I have made three custom cells : `firstNameTableViewCell` , `lastNameTableViewCell`,`birthdayTableViewCell` : All of this three cells contains a label ans a `textfield`.I want that when the user touch the corresponding cell , he will be able to change his data.

Technically , I have used the tableView's delegate methods : `cellForRowAtIndexPath` & `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but I don't have what I want : When I open the interface : the label is disappering and when i touch the corresponding cell , nothing that changes . 
This my code :

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0 : {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"genderCell"];
        genderTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tableUserData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.maleImageView = [cell  showGender:self.gender];
        cell.femaleImageView =[cell  showGender:self.gender];

        return cell ;

        break;
    }

    case 1 : {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"firstNameCell"];
        firstNameTableViewCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tableUserData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.firstNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.firstName];
        cell.firstNameTextField.hidden =YES ;
        return cell;
        break;
    }

    case 2 : {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"lastNameCell"];
        lastNameTableViewCell  *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tableUserData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.lastNameLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.lastName];

        cell.lastNameTextField.hidden = YES ;
        return cell;
        break;
    }


    case 3 : {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"BirthDayCell"];
        birthDayTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tableUserData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.birthDaylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.birthDay];
        cell.birthDayTextField.hidden = YES ;
        return cell;

        break;
    }


    case 4 : {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"heightCell"];
        heightTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tableUserData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.heightUnityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.heightUnity];
        self.height = [cell.heightTextField.text   floatValue];

        return cell;
        break;
    }


    case 5 : {

        NSString *cellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"weightCell"];
        weightTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tableUserData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        cell.weightUnityLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.weightUnity];
        self.weight = [cell.weightTextField.text   floatValue];

        return cell;
        break;
    }


    default:
        break ;
}

return nil ;
     }


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"%ld",indexPath.row);

if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    firstNameTableViewCell *cell = [firstNameTableViewCell new];
    cell.firstNameLabel.hidden = YES ;
    cell.firstNameTextField.hidden = NO ;
    cell.firstNameTextField.text = cell.firstNameLabel.text ;
    [self.userDataTableView  reloadData];
}

else   if (indexPath.row == 2) {

    lastNameTableViewCell *cell = [lastNameTableViewCell new];
    cell.lastNameLabel.hidden = YES ;
    cell.lastNameTextField.hidden = NO ;
    cell.lastNameTextField.text = cell.lastNameLabel.text ;
    [self.userDataTableView  reloadData];
}
else   if (indexPath.row == 3) {

    birthDayTableViewCell *cell = [birthDayTableViewCell new];
    cell.birthDaylabel.hidden = YES ;
    cell.birthDayTextField.hidden = NO ;
    cell.birthDayTextField.text = cell.birthDaylabel.text ;
    [self.userDataTableView  reloadData];
}
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use both a label and a text field? Its hard to keep them in sync. Just use a textfield and disable it if it's currently supposed to be read-only.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr how can I disable it if it's currently supposed to be read-only ??

Comment: UITextField is a subclass of UIControl, you can set enabled to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Inside:

`-(void)tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`

It is much better if you'll just use the indexPath to return the cell like:

```
firstNameTableViewCell *cell = (firstNameTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)];
..
cell.firstNameTextField.hidden = NO ;
cell.firstNameTextField.text = cell.firstNameLabel.text;

// but do not reload the table yet..
```

Instead make `cell.firstNameTextField` as the first responder and let the user enter necessary data..

`[cell.firstNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

if the user is done editing and you have database for that, update your database on DONE, then your table dataSource (`self.tableUserData`), only then you need the `[self.userDataTableView  reloadData];`, and i think you dont really want to reload the whole table for that single edit,`[self.userDataTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)]`  reloading only the target indexPath is much more suitable for that..

`-reloadData` means '*reloading everything in the table based from your array data source*'. meaning settings of values made inside:

`-(void)tableView:tableView willDisplayingCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`

and

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`

ex:

`cell.firstNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.firstName];
cell.lastNameTextField.hidden = YES ;`

will be refreshed and set as is...

**Edit**

Also i've noticed that you didn't allocate your cells if nil after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`(i wonder why your app is not crashing because of it), anyway it is good for the memory to reuseCells like:

```
firstNameTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
     cell = [[firstNameTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Comment: @Oyeoj I have followed your advices and I have applied them but the problem is when I open the profile interface , the tableView should display the corresponding label for each cell : nothing that can be displayed even before touching each cel . And when i touch the corresponding cell , also nothing that happen : it is empty .

Comment: Nothing was displayed? my advance was modification inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, how come there are no content shown now?  have you checked your dataSource, are you sure it is not nil?

Comment: how can i  check  my dataSource ??

Comment: You log it like: `NSLog(@"%@", self.tableUserData);` or `NSLog(@"%@", self.tableUserData.count > 0 ? @"not empty" : @"empty");`

Comment: my issue is that the two data self.firstName and self.lastName aren't null but when the table view is displayed the two label in the two cells are null .